# How To Generate Soap Request Without Envelop, Header & Body

Tags: java, soap

I'm working on a project that i need to send requests without 
and envlope, header or body objects as in below

```
<Response>
   <SrvType>GET_NUMBER_DETAILS</SrvType>
   <AppName>IVR</AppName>
   <ClientSessionId>KSJ77SDS678DF7</ClientSessionId>
   <ClientTxnId>2145</ClientTxnId>
   <MsgOrigin>ECHELON</MsgOrigin>
   <MsgDest>IVRGW</MsgDest>
   <Timestamp>03/07/2013 15:32:49:357</Timestamp>
   <RespCode>SC0000</RespCode>
   <RespDesc>SUCCESS</RespDesc>
   <Data>
      <Detail>
         <Param>
            <Name>MSISDN</Name>
            <Value>987667756</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>ICCID</Name>
            <Value>87655467898776544568</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>IMSI</Name>
            <Value>879097897883212</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>Status</Name>
            <Value>ACTIVE</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>LastStatusChangeDate</Name>
            <Value>30/12/2012</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>CreationDate</Name>
            <Value>22/11/2012</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>ActivationDate</Name>
            <Value>30/12/2012</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>LastUpdationDate</Name>
            <Value>30/12/2012</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>PIN1</Name>
            <Value>0000</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>PIN2</Name>
            <Value>1020</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>PUK1</Name>
            <Value>24180410</Value>
         </Param>
         <Param>
            <Name>PUK2</Name>
            <Value>23171840</Value>
         </Param>
      </Detail>
   </Data>
</Response>
```

so far my best attempt yielded this below
Is there a way request above can be generated

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body/>
   <Request>
      <SrvType>GET_NUMBER_DETAILS</SrvType>
      <Username>Tigocare</Username>
      <Password>Tigocare1234</Password>
      <AppName>Tigocare</AppName>
      <ClientSessionId>617502789907903890</ClientSessionId>
      <ClientTxnId>619246981138215392</ClientTxnId>
      <MsgOrigin>Tigocare</MsgOrigin>
      <MsgDest>ECHELON</MsgDest>
      <Timestamp>08-06-2015 15:56:08:001</Timestamp>
      <Data>
         GET_NUMBER_DETAILS
         <Detail>
            <Param>
               <Name>NumberType</Name>
               <Value>3</Value>
            </Param>
            <Param>
               <Name>MSISDN</Name>
               <Value>277551488</Value>
            </Param>
         </Detail>
      </Data>
   </Request>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

/*................................................................................................................................................
........................................................................*/

Comment: open the envelope, take out the content? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a SOAP message without SOAP envelope and body as they are required parameters for any message to confirm to SOAP standard. In case of your requirement, you can create a normal XML message with all the tags and attributes necessary. But, you will have to take care of all the tags used with their names etc.

Comment: thanks very much,
Been so caught up in working with Soap Messages, i'd completely forgotten about normal XML Messages.